# Javascript code is not working in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I wrote a code to solve `this` keyword issues in `setTimeout()` function. And tried to run it in node and it showed throw err; can't find module error. Then I tried to run it in a browser and it worked. I mean how to know when to test our code in nodejs and when not. This is my code

```
function person () {
    var firstName ;
    var _this_ = this;

    return {
        saveContext: function(context) {
        _this_ = context;
    },
        setName: function(name) {
        _this_.firstName = name;
    },
        getName: function() {
        console.log(_this_.firstName);
    }
  };
}

var employee1 = new person();
employee1.saveContext(employee1);

employee1.setName('Steve');
employee1.getName();

setTimeout(employee1.getName, 1000);
```

Comment: Works for me in both Node 4 and Node 6. I wouldn't, at all, recommend writing code like that, but it works.

Comment: *"Or how can I improve my code. "* is too broad for SO. You might review the [guidelines over at codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and, if this is in keeping with them, post there.

Comment: Please post the full error and the full relevant source code. We can't help you debug what we can't see.

Comment: Yes, it works now! Thanks, I was just practising to solve the issue. And I will keep that in mind :) @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Sorry for it. Edited my question now @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "can't find module" error is thrown when:

- You try running node on a non-existent file.
- The file exists, but it's not in that directory.
- You require a file which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks! :) The file was up a directory from workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure npm port is running using below command to overcome running again and again server.

nodemon entryfilename.js

Secondly , test using npm if installed properly in your root directory.